# Laravel add an element to array inside a json column

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

Let's say we have a user with parameters field like this:

```
User::first()->parameters
=> [
     "pins" => [
       1,
     ],
   ]
```

Now I want to add another pin to have something like this:

```
User::first()->parameters['pins']
=> [
     2,
     1,
   ]
```

Currently I'm doing this with the following query:

```
User::first()->update(['parameters' => ['pins' => array_merge([2], User::first()->parameters['pins'])]])
```

I was wonder if there is any Eloquent way to do that without fetching the pins first (I mean without `User::first()->parameters['pins']`). Because mysql suport it with `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way as you did currently, to update an array of a field.

For betterment you might use an `one to many` table naming like `user_parameters` and use something like this `$user->parameter()->create()` using eloquent relationship, to insert new value without fetching old array.